# sqlalchemy can't open database file

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file.
I've created a database file called database.db (not that special) which automatically got put in a folder called 'instance'. When I take it out of the folder/subdirectory and in the same directory as my app.py file and delete the old 'instance' folder it just gets recreated whenever I run the app.py again. I don't think that this is the problem regarding the relative path but more with the database itself, or with the route I'm using to get there. I've been stuck at this error for 3 days already and this is my last hope lol.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///instance/database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'ef757588f3eafb534e3bfc7d349e3d91'
login_manager = LoginManager(app)

@login_manager.user_loader 
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
   email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
   password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
   pfp_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')

   def __repr__(self):
      return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.pfp_file}')"
   
class Pizza(db.Model):
    Item_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    Price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Pizza('{self.Item_ID}', '{self.Price}', '{self.date_posted}')"
    

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
   username = StringField('Username', 
                          validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
   email = StringField('Email',
                       validators= [DataRequired(), Email()])
   password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
   confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                    validators= [DataRequired(), EqualTo(password)])
   submit = SubmitField('Sign up')

   def validate_username(self, username):
       user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
       if user:
           raise ValidationError('That username already exists')
       
   def validate_email(self, email):
       user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
       if user:
           raise ValidationError('That email is already taken.')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
   email = StringField('Email',
                       validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
   password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
   remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
   submit = SubmitField('Login') 

@app.route('/Register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}, welcome to the family!')
        return redirect('/Login')
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
 


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="">
    <form method="POST", action="/Register">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Join the family today.</legend>
            <div>
                {{ form.username.label }}
                {{ form.username }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.email.label }}
                {{ form.email }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.password.label }}
                {{ form.password }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.confirm_password.label }}
                {{ form.confirm_password }}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
            {{ form.submit }}
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
        <small>
            Already have an account? <a class="ml-2" href="../Login">Sign in</a>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could check the answers to [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflask-sqlalchemy%5D+OperationalError+open+is%3Aq+answers%3A1..) and perhaps [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%5Bsqlite%5D+OperationalError+open+is%3Aq+answers%3A1..)

Comment: Did you create an empty db file? You'll have to run migrations to put your model inside the database. You'll probably have to run this command `python manage.py migrate`